# WordPress comment_form() $fields arg not taking affect

Tags: wordpress, filter

I am trying to add a comment form using the `comment_form()` function. When I don't pass in any arguments, the only field that shows up is the comment textarea field. I need to add in the author and email fields. I am trying to do this using the `fields` arguments.

```
$args = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">Name</label><input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" /></p>'
    ),
    'title_reply' => null,
    'logged_in_as' => null,
    'submit_button' => '<input name="%1$s" type="submit" id="%2$s" class="%3$s btn btn-primary" value="%4$s" />'
);
comment_form($args);
```

I am still just getting the comment textarea. I have checked the markup with Inspect Element and nothing is being added. The three additional arguments, `title_reply, logged_in_as, submit_button` all work fine.

Additionally, I have also tried using `apply_filters` which also did not work.

```
'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(
    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">Name</label><input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" /></p>'
)),
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are checking the comment form when you are logged in. It happens sometimes. Try to log out or check it via browser incognito mode.
And another important setting from `Dashbord->Settings->Discussion-- Comment author must fill out name and email` mark this field.
[image: This Comment author must fill out name and email should be checked]